# What happens when the random library doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have 2 commands that worked before and now no, no errors appear!

The random library is imported, also all the discord!

Bot connects, all commands work less
meme and random

**Libraries imported into the code:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import random 
import aiohttp
import os
import asyncio

from urllib import parse, request
import re
```

**The code of both commands**

Before the random worked now no, and errors do not appear!

```
@bot.command()
async def random(ctx):
    await ctx.send(random.randint(0,50))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def meme(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="meme", description="test")

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        async with cs.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/new.json?sort=hot') as r:
            res = await r.json()
            embed.set_image(res['data']['children'] [random.randint(0, 25)]['data']['url'])
            await client.say(embed=embed)
```

**Any solution, the console is clean and the bot works!**

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working? You seem to be saying that it's working and not working, without making a clear distinction between the two situations. When does it work and what do you change before it stops working?

Comment: @Blckknght
The console has no errors when executing the command, before they worked, now they don't!

I don't know why!
I don't know what is wrong!

What I know is that the random library is null, as it has nothing!

You don't have to install it with the pip or anything else

Comment: The question I was asking was, what is different between "before" and "now". What did you change? We can't tell which parts of the code are unmodified and which ones you've just written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the `random` module's name with your `async def random(ctx)` function. Change the name of that function, it should work.

Comment: When it worked, the command had another name! now has the name random!

Comment: It doesn't work, even if you change the command name!

Comment: Wait wait, the function was to change!
The command already works!

Thanks you!